# Prevent HtmlAgilityPack from automatically adding unclosed tags

Tags: c#, html, razor, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

**Goal** : Remove Inline-styles and add class using Html-Agility-Pack in Razor html in MVC.

It's been a 2 days since trying to figure out a solution for parsing Razor html using Html-Agility-Pack
I do know that Html-Agility-Pack is not good for parsing razor. I know by applying logic into it, we can build this thing up, would need your help.

**Problem :** Html-Agility-Pack when encounters un-closed tags, it tries to add automatically tags in the HTML structure, what I need to achieve is Html-Agility-Pack should not add any extra tags after html is parsed.

Below is the problem I am facing, extra tags are added. It treats c# Type  as a tag and adds in document.

```
<span>(@((Session["Usernames"] as List<Username>)[0].Name))</span>

<span>(@((Session["Usernames"] as List<Username>)[0].Name))</Username></span>
```

**Code** I tried below code but I cant find any options which will help in achieving this

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.OptionCheckSyntax = false;
document.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
document.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
document.LoadHtml(line);


var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@style]")[0];
if (node.Attributes["class"] != null)
{
   var NodeClass = node.Attributes["class"].Value;
   node.SetAttributeValue("class", NodeClass + " " + className);
}
else
{
   node.Attributes.Add("class", className);
}
```

Comment: The purpose of HTML Agility Pack is to extract data from HTML.  Why do you care what it does with the source HTML's tags?

Comment: Please check Goal I am trying to achieve, I have edited the question

Comment: OK.  Same question.  Why do you care that HTML Agility Pack closes your tags?

Comment: I am parsing a html line, remove style tags, adding class , replace my razor dom with parsed Html-Agility-Pack DOM

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do.  What I don't understand is your insistence on preserving unclosed tags.

Comment: As I am reading line by line, a particular Tag can have closing Tag on next, so I dont want Html-Agility-Pack to add closing Tag on 1st line.

Comment: I guess you'd better provide an example of the original HTML, and a corresponding HTML example of how HTML Agility Pack is closing tags that it shoudn't.

Comment: Please check example I have posted on question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210877/discussion-between-manoj-soma-and-robert-harvey).